# Accessing inner text from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:TestCRForm:-myXSD-2013-01-09T15-23-27" solutionVersion="1.0.0.285" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://win-rskupn6mf2b:2331/TestCRForm/Forms/template.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-01-09T15:23:27" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
    <my:VendorName>Vendor Name1</my:VendorName>
    <my:Assignedto>Asigner</my:Assignedto>
    <my:SOWNumber></my:SOWNumber>
    <my:DraftStarted xsi:nil="true"></my:DraftStarted>
    <my:DateComplete xsi:nil="true"></my:DateComplete>
    <my:GLCode>Material No1</my:GLCode>
    <my:LogID>2013-09-05T22:44:09</my:LogID>
    <my:Status>New</my:Status>
    <my:ProjectDescription>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve">
      <p>​ THIS TEXT</p>
    </html>
  </my:ProjectDescription>

</my:myFields>
```

I am able to access fields inside tag : `VendorName` & `AssignedTo` using following

```
XmlNodeList nodelist1 = xml.GetElementsByTagName("my:myFields");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist1)
            text_name = node["my:VendorName"].InnerText;
```

But i am not able to access inner text inside ProjectDescription tag i.e. "THIS TEXT" using

```
XmlNodeList nodelist1 = xml.GetElementsByTagName("my:myFields/my:ProjectDescription/html");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist1)
                text1 = node["p"].InnerText;
```

While running this in debug mode i get NULL in nodelist1.

Please suggest me a method to do this.

Comment: I think my:myFields/my:ProjectDescription/html is not the correct syntax. try getting it seperatly. check out this : http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/179393-how-retrieve-xml-sublevel-using-getelementsbytagname

Comment: I have tried it for another simple xml file that had no namespace & it was working fine. Some thing to do with name space but i am unable to figure it out exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-01-09T15:23:27");
nsm.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

XmlNodeList nodelist1 = xml.SelectNodes("my:myFields/my:ProjectDescription/x:html",nsm);
foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist1)
    Console.WriteLine(node["p"].InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
XmlNodeList nodelist1 = xml.SelectNodes("my:myFields/my:ProjectDescription");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist1)
            {
                text1 = node["html"].InnerText;
            }
```

It converts the tag.innerText to paragraph formatting even in the string text1. You can trim it down from there.

Comment: Here is my full testing code which works.

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load("text.xml");


            string text1;
            XmlNodeList nodelist1 = doc.SelectNodes("myFields/ProjectDescription");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist1)
            {
                text1 = node["html"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(text1);
            }

Comment: It throws exception. Try with the xml in question. You need `XmlNamespaceManager` as in my answer. You test with `myFields/ProjectDescription`, but add `my:` in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` and `XPath`. I think you could use the XPath the best. It explains the namespace issue I think.

**XPath:**

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

var document = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"D:\test.xml");
var namespaceManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(new System.Xml.NameTable());
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-01-09T15:23:27");
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
var pValue = document.XPathSelectElement("/my:myFields/my:ProjectDescription/html:html/html:p", namespaceManager).Value;
```

**XDocument:**

```
var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"D:\test.xml");

var myNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-01-09T15:23:27";
var htmlNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

var myFields = xml.Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get("myFields", myNamespace));
var projectDescription = myFields.Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get("ProjectDescription", myNamespace));
var htmlTag = projectDescription.Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get("html", htmlNamespace));
var pTag = htmlTag.Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get("p", htmlNamespace));

var pValue = pTag.Value;
```